Standard BLE library android.bluetooth. DFU mode
How do I download DFU firmware via the BLE standard library (android.bluetooth) in Android Studio?
I am using an NRF controller. I debug via NRF Connect. There is an option to upload firmware via DFU in the application. How can I do the same via Java code in Android Studio? Is there a similar possibility in android.bluetooth library (I use it for gatt connection)? Or do I need to use a third party library?
Tried looking in Android documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/bluetooth/package-summary) and in the library sources. But I couldn't find it.

There is no specific DFU update method in the android.bluetooth library you can use. You can

Implement the update process yourself by following the documentation of your nRF hardware. There should be a section about the specific DFU process including all required steps to send your DFU package
Use the Android DFU library provided by Nordic Semiconductor

